# Get date of timeseries object

Tags: r, date, time-series

I have a separately created time series object with daily frequency:

```
my.timeseries= ts(data= 1:10, start= c(2014,1,1), frequency = 365.25)
```

How can I get back the dates as POSIXct vector (`"2014-01-01 UTC"` ...)  from this time series object?

Comment: `ts` does nto work well for dates.   Suggest you use zoo or xts.  `library(zoo); z <- zooreg(1:10, as.Date("2014-01-01"))`

Comment: Unfortunately the ts object exists already. So I look for a solution which handles ts.

Comment: If you know that `my.timeseries` consists of sequential dates starting at the beginning of a year then this will convert it to a zooreg series with Date class index: `zooreg(coredata(my.timeseries), as.Date(as.yearmon(start(my.timeseries))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one potential method. I'm not really sure if it should be done this way, but it seems to work.

With your existing time series, try

```
p <- paste(attr(my.timeseries, "tsp")[1], my.timeseries)
as.POSIXct(as.Date(p, "%Y %j"))
#  [1] "2014-01-01 UTC" "2014-01-02 UTC" "2014-01-03 UTC"
#  [4] "2014-01-04 UTC" "2014-01-05 UTC" "2014-01-06 UTC"
#  [7] "2014-01-07 UTC" "2014-01-08 UTC" "2014-01-09 UTC"
# [10] "2014-01-10 UTC"
```

As noted by G. Grothendieck in the comments, here is a more general solution

```
p <- paste(start(my.timeseries), seq_along(my.timeseries))
as.Date(p, "%Y %j")
# [1] "2014-01-01" "2014-01-02" "2014-01-03" "2014-01-04"
# [5] "2014-01-05" "2014-01-06" "2014-01-07" "2014-01-08"
# [9] "2014-01-09" "2014-01-10"
```

`as.Date` might be better to avoid any time-zone issues.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly advise you to use xts object instead of ts.

Here is a code replicating what you want :

```
library(xts)
my.index = seq(from = as.Date("2014-01-01"), by = "day", length.out = 10)
my.timeseries = xts(x = 1:10, order.by = my.index)
index(my.timeseries)
```

Let us know if that helps :)

Romain

Comment: Thx.      
Unfortunately the ts object exists already. So I look for a solution which handles ts.